# How can we represent a "double" type matrix as an RGB image in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, matrix, rgb, colormatrix

I did a wavelet transforms of 4 images and finally after my modifications(ie.,fusion of these images), and taking inverse wavelet transform, I am left with the wavelet coefficients - approximation matrix and the Horizontal, Vertical and Diagonal detail matrices. I want to know how to display the color image version of the inverse transform.

I am doing my coding using MATLAB 7.9. Thanks in advance [:)]...

Comment: It would help if you show the relevant code parts..

Answer (score 0):

[`imagesc()`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/imagesc.html)?